# Efficiency and effectiveness of Java/.NET interoperability tools (IKVM, JNBridge etc.)

Tags: java, .net, interop, ikvm

I'm looking into the use of Java/.NET interoperability tools such as IKVM and JNBridge to allow a .NET client to run a Java-based program.  Do these and similar tools tend to cause the program to run more slowly or with greater memory overhead, relative to a simple .NET implementation of the client?  Are there any other serious advantages or disadvantages of any or all of the tools that I should be aware of (security, bugginess, whatnot)?  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

[Note: I'm with JNBridge.]

We generally don't publish benchmarking information, as we encourage prospective users to try the product themselves.  Also, different users have different requirements and run on different platforms, so our internal benchmarks likely wouldn't be relevant.

That said, there is some overhead in the cross-platform calls relating to marshalling and unmarshalling arguments and return values, and to network overhead (when socket-based tcp/binary communications is used -- shared memory communications, which runs the .NET and Java in the same process, has no network overhead).  We encourage you to run some relevant examples to see how JNBridgePro performance works for you.

Regarding your other questions, please feel free to contact us at info @ jnbridge dot com, and we would be happy to provide you with additional information.  There are also customer case studies on our site, which will give you some idea of the scenarios in which JNBridgePro has been successfully used.

Comment: Thanks for trying to answer this question.  We've decided on our tools as of now.